# Why doesn't the website “ifconfig.me” show the IPv4 address? It shows only IPv6 address?

Tags: networking, ip

I just found out about this website, [ifconfig.me](https://ifconfig.me), good info. Except there is no IPv4 info.

Why is this?

This info would make this the perfect tool if it included IPv4 info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl -6 ifconfig.me` shows my IPv6 address, while `curl -4 ifconfig.me` shows my IPv4 address. So it's only showing the one you used for this connection.

Comment: Great answer and good thinking!